# Is it possible to check if a user's input is one of the options of a case loop?

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a script which is run like so:

```
./check.sh site_location
```

The script is written using a case loop for each one of the 5 geo-location sites of my company.

I want to make sure that the user's input is one of the possibilities I added in the case options or the script will exit with an error code.

```
function usage() {
        echo "Usage: $0 SiteName"
        echo "SiteName can be: ny / ny4a / lax / ams / sg / all "
}

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        usage
        exit 1
fi

if [ $1 != "ny" ] || [ $1 != "ny4a" ] || [ $1 != "lax" ] || [ $1 != "ams" ] || [ $1 != "sg" ] || [ $1 != "all" ]; then
        usage
        exit 1
fi
```

I'm 100% positive that I have a mistake in the way I wrote the second IF statement ("if statement or statement or statement..."). How can I fix this?

Edit:
The full script looks like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This scripts checks the the cache sync between the proxies in each one of the data centers.
# Script by Itai Ganot
#
ny4="ny4.company.com"
lax="lax.company.com"
ams="ams2.company.com"
sg="sg.company.com"
dcdny="nyproxy"
dcdny4a="ny4a"
dcdams="ams"
dcdlax="la"
dcdsg="sg"
checkerPath="/workspace/test/java2db/scripts/"
function usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 SiteName"
    echo "SiteName can be: ny / ny4a / lax / ams / sg / all "
}
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    usage
    exit 1
fi
#if [ $1 != "ny" ] || [ $1 != "ny4a" ] || [ $1 != "lax" ] || [ $1 != "ams" ] || [ $1 != "sg" ] || [ $1 != "all" ]; then
#   usage
#        exit 1
#fi
    case $1 in
    ny)
    echo -e "\e[36m #===# NY: #===#\e[0m"
    cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdny  | grep $ny4  | awk -F',' '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq -c
    read -r -p "Would you like to view specific list? [y/n] " reply
    if [ "$reply" = "y" ];
        then 
            cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdny  | grep $ny4
    fi
    ;;
    ny4a)
    echo -e "\e[36m #===# NY4A: #===#\e[0m"
    cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdny4a  | grep $ny4  | awk -F',' '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq -c
    read -r -p "Would you like to view specific list? [y/n] " reply
    if [ "$reply" = "y" ];
        then
            cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdny4a  | grep $ny4
    fi
    ;;
    lax)
    echo -e "\e[36m #===# LAX: #===#\e[0m"
    cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdlax  | grep $lax  | awk -F',' '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq -c
    read -r -p "Would you like to view specific list? [y/n] " reply
    if [ "$reply" = "y" ];
        then
            cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dclax  | grep $lax
    fi
    ;;
    sg)
    echo -e "\e[36m #===# SG: #===#\e[0m"
    cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdsg  | grep $sg  | awk -F',' '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq -c
    read -r -p "Would you like to view specific list? [y/n] " reply
    if [ "$reply" = "y" ];
        then
            cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdsg  | grep $sg
    fi
    ;;
    ams)
    echo -e "\e[36m #===# AMS: #===#\e[0m"
    cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdams  | grep $ams  | awk -F',' '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq -c
    read -r -p "Would you like to view specific list? [y/n] " reply
    if [ "$reply" = "y" ];
        then
            cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdams  | grep $ams
    fi
    ;;
    all)
    echo -e "\e[36m #===# NY: #===#\e[0m"
    cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdny  | grep $ny4  | awk -F',' '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq -c
    echo -e "\e[36m #===# NY4A: #===#\e[0m"
    cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdny4a  | grep $ny4  | awk -F',' '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq -c
    echo -e "\e[36m #===# LAX: #===#\e[0m"
    cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdlax  | grep $lax  | awk -F',' '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq -c
    echo -e "\e[36m #===# SG: #===#\e[0m"
    cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdsg  | grep $sg  | awk -F',' '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq -c
    echo -e "\e[36m #===# AMS: #===#\e[0m"
    cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdams  | grep $ams  | awk -F',' '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq -c
    read -r -p "Would you like to view specific list? [y/n] " reply
    if [ "$reply" = "y" ];
        then
            echo -e "\e[36m #===# NY: #===#\e[0m"
            cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdny  | grep $ny4
            echo -e "\e[36m #===# NY4A: #===#\e[0m"
            cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdny4a  | grep $ny4
            echo -e "\e[36m #===# LAX: #===#\e[0m"
            cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdlax  | grep $lax
            echo -e "\e[36m #===# SG: #===#\e[0m"
            cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdsg  | grep $sg
            echo -e "\e[36m #===# AMS: #===#\e[0m"
            cd $checkerPath && ant proxy-size -Ddcd=$dcdams  | grep $ams
    fi
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Use `case`..`esac` construct? No need for the long if..

Comment: & If you "have to" use if, you need `&&` between the conditions, not `||` :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `case` to compactify your conditionals:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function usage() {
        echo "Usage: $0 SiteName"
        echo "SiteName can be: ny / ny4a / lax / ams / sg / all "
}

case "$1" in
ny|ny4a|lax|ams|sg|all) ;;
*) usage ; exit 1; ;;
esac
```